How can I write an Excel VBA function to add a ":" if the field doesn't have a colon, or leave it as is if it does have one?
Currently I have this working with an Excel formula, but would like to include it in my VBA code if possible. If a user enters a time in a text field in the VBA application, they can either enter it with the colon or without, and it will make sure the text ends up with a colon. When text is entered, I have a cell in Excel being updated with that text. The following formula in Excel gives me what I want, but I'd like to be able to get this done from VBA so I don't have to find every instance of that cell reference in my code and update it to something else.
=IF(COUNTIF(B2, "*" & ":" & "*"), B2, REPLACE(B2,LEN(B2)-1,0,":"))
Any ideas? I'm not as familiar with VBA code as I am with Excel formulas.
I've tried something like this in VBA, but it screams at me with red text when I try to enter it in:
'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF(B2, "*" & ":" & "*"), B2, REPLACE(B2,LEN(B2)-1,0,":"))"

Would help to provide some examples of the types of values which might be entered

The user will enter a time with or without a colon. Some examples are 1000, 10:00, 0856, 08:56, 2100, and 23:56. If they enter 1234, it needs to change it to be 12:34. If they enter 15:36, it will stay as 15:36.

Right now, I've got the time entered into the text field in VBA populating into a certain cell in Excel and I set up a formula in a different cell to make it do what I want based off of that first cell. But I would like it to just populate correctly in the cell where the VBA text field sends the entered data originally so I don't have to use an additional, unneeded cell, in Excel.

Correct Time in Cells Formatted As Text

So you want to do something that cannot be done using formulas i.e. correct what the user entered in place.
In this case, the data to be corrected is in column B, starting with B2 (single cell) and continuing to the last non-empty row (single column).
I wrote the code so you could easily modify the behavior for each case. You could possibly improve (ask another question) once you figure out what exactly should happen in each case.


Standard Module, e.g. Module1 (VBE-->Insert-->Module)
Single Cell
Sub CorrectTimeSingleCell()
    
    ' Read.
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim cell As Range: Set cell = ws.Range("B2")
    Dim rStr As String: rStr = CStr(cell.Value)
    
    ' Modify.
    
    If InStr(rStr, ":") = 0 Then ' doesn't contain a colon
        Select Case Len(rStr)
            Case 0
                rStr = "00:00"
            Case 1
                rStr = "00:0" & rStr
            Case 2
                rStr = "00:" & rStr
            Case 3
                rStr = "0" & Left(rStr, 1) & ":" & Right(rStr, 2)
            Case 4
                rStr = Left(rStr, 2) & ":" & Right(rStr, 2)
            Case Else
                rStr = Mid(rStr, 1, Len(rStr) - 2) & ":" & Right(rStr, 2)
        End Select
    Else ' contains a colon
        ' do nothing?
    End If
    
    ' Write.
    
    cell.Value = rStr
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Time corrected.", vbInformation
    
End Sub

Single Column
Sub CorrectTime()

    ' Define constants.
    
    Const TOP_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "B2"

    ' Read.
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim rg As Range, RowsCount As Long
    
    With ws.Range(TOP_CELL_ADDRESS)
        RowsCount = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If RowsCount < 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data
        Set rg = .Resize(RowsCount)
    End With
    
    Dim Data() As Variant
    
    If RowsCount = 1 Then
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
    Else
        Data = rg.Value
    End If

    ' Modify.
    
    Dim r As Long, rStr As String
     
    For r = 1 To RowsCount
        rStr = CStr(Data(r, 1))
        If InStr(rStr, ":") = 0 Then ' doesn't contain a colon
            Select Case Len(rStr)
                Case 0
                    rStr = "00:00"
                Case 1
                    rStr = "00:0" & rStr
                Case 2
                    rStr = "00:" & rStr
                Case 3
                    rStr = "0" & Left(rStr, 1) & ":" & Right(rStr, 2)
                Case 4
                    rStr = Left(rStr, 2) & ":" & Right(rStr, 2)
                Case Else
                    rStr = Mid(rStr, 1, Len(rStr) - 2) & ":" & Right(rStr, 2)
            End Select
            Data(r, 1) = rStr
        Else ' contains a colon
            ' do nothing!?
        End If
    Next r

    ' Write.
    
    rg.Value = Data

    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Times corrected.", vbInformation
    
End Sub


The quotation marks in the middle of the formula are the issue.  For a quotation mark to appear in the formula you need to use a pair ("").
Also the formula you entered in vba would create a circular reference on cell B2.  If the formula you entered in the cell gives you the result you want, try:
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF(B2,""*"" & "":"" & ""*""), B2, REPLACE(B2,LEN(B2)-1,0,"":""))"
